# Formula to express a number with even digits

Tags: arithmetic, integers

In a algorithm book I'm reading there's this paragraph (it concerns a recursive algorithm for integer multiplication):

*In general, a number $x$ with an even number $n$ of digits can be expressed in terms of two $n/2$-digit numbers, its first half $a$ and second half $b$:*

$x=10^{n/2} * a + b$

I'm not sure how to apply this formula and what "*...its first half $a$ and second half $b$*" means exactly.

Suppose $x = 5112$.

This number has $n = 4$ even digits, therefore it should involve a multiplication for $10^{4/2}$; what are $a$ and $b$ in this case?

Comment: $5112 = 5100+12 = 100\cdot 51 + 12 = 10^2\cdot 51 + 12$, however you wish to write it if you insist to help your thought process

Comment: @ JMoravitz yes but this numbers are not two $n/2$- digit numbers

Comment: $51$ is not a $4/2=2$ digit number?  In what way do you consider $51$ to not be a two-digit number?  I can count the digits.... $5$ is the first digit in $51$... and $1$ is the second digit in $51$... that's two digits...

Comment: @JMoravitz you only wrote $5112 = 5100 + 12$ before, now i understand

Comment: Beside, for $x = 5000$ we have $5000 = 10^2 * 50 + 0$, but only $a$ is a $n/2$ digit number

Comment: Sure, the author may have been too imprecise in how they worded things... "*up to n/2 digits number*" may have been more appropriate... but you are thinking too much about this when it should be incredibly simple.  You can write a large number as the sum of two numbers... where the first number is comprised by the first however many digits of the original number multiplied by a power of ten... and the second number is comprised by the remaining digits.  $12345678$ is equal to $1234\cdot 10^4+5678$.  That is all the author is trying to get across.

Comment: There is no explicit need for this to be precisely an even number of digits to begin with, nor is there an explicit need for the point where they split to be precisely in the middle.  You can also write $12345678$ to be equal to $12\cdot 10^6+345678$ or as $1234567\cdot 10 + 8$ or however else.  The whole point of them splitting it as they do is that they intend to make multiplication a bit "easier" to manage... noting that $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$ might involve smaller numbers than $(X)\cdot (Y)$ might have...

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, this is a good point and clarifies my original doubt. Thank you